# Dash eater address

Tags: dash

Is there any dash adddress where all outputs are guaranteed to stay unspent?

Like bitcoin `1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE` in dash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not to use OP_RETURN  output script to burn coins?

Comment: because I need unspent output and when would I use OP_RETURN there will be none

Comment: OP_RETURN is unspent and provable unspendable output :) The only reason not to use this is that users know how to send funds to regular addresses like 1bitcoinEater... and do not know how to create OP_RETURN outputs

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is nothing special about the `1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE` address, if someone by chance did manage to find the private key for it they could spend the bitcoins there. The reason it is trusted as unspendable is that to find a private key for a given address is impossible with our current knowledge of elliptic curve cryptography (and RIPEMD-160), if it was possible then bitcoin along with many other security systems would be completely broken. That specific address is trusted because it is completely made up of english words other than the checksum at the end (which is there to make it a valid bitcoin address), so it can be basically guaranteed that no one has the private key for it.

So technically any valid address for dash that you generate would be equally unspendable without the corresponding private key, and thus an address of this sort could easily be created for dash by coming up with a similar string as the bitcoinEater, make sure its obviously picked based on the address itself so people will believe that you don't have the private key for it, e.g. `DashDevourerAddressDontSend`, and then generate the appropriate checksum with the right prefix for it to make it a valid address.